# Symfony 1.4: Accessing Doctrine from within custom PHP class

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have a custom library that lives in `apps/frontend/lib/`. This class needs to access `Doctrine_Query` and a few other basic symfony classes.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the [symfony autoloader](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/14-Other-Configuration-Files) first, and then just use your classes. Everything is available (almost) everywhere in a symfony 1.x project.